# Using arcpy.CopyFeatures_management results in a 000210 using a database connection that does not contain saved credentials

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, standard-license-level, error-000210

Currently have a problem running CopyFeatures_management in ESRI's ArcGIS 10.1

The following shows two Enterprise Geodatabase connection files. One includes the username and password and the other one doesn't. While still at 10.0 (SP5) running this script would result in the Database Connection prompt appearing. Since installing 10.1 (SP1 + Quality Patch) it no longer does and simply fails with error 000210.

It works fine if I switch the script to use the connection file with the credentials saved into it.

So far tested on XP and Server 2008.

Please see the script below:

```
import os, sys
import arceditor, arcpy

# Define the source
source_fc_full_path = r'C:\_SCRATCH\DB_work\test_upload_data.gdb\ut_random_pts_10_gdb'

# Two connection files - one with the user credentials saved to it
# the other without. Under 10.0 (SP5) using the connection string without
# the credentials would result in a Database Connection box appearing. At 10.1
# this no longer happens.
# Works fine if I switch the workspace.
# NOTE - one of them is commented out for obvious reasons.
target_wkspace = r'C:\_SCRATCH\DB_work\user_pass_not_saved.sde'
#target_wkspace = r'C:\_SCRATCH\DB_work\user_pass_saved.sde'

target_fc = r'<DB_NAME>.<SCHEMA_NAME>.UT_RANDOM_PTS_10_GDB'

# Define the full target path
target_fc_full_path = os.path.join(target_wkspace, target_fc)

# Run the command that now fails at 10.1 with a 000210 if the connection string does not include user credentials saved into it...
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(source_fc_full_path,target_fc_full_path,"","0","0","0")
```

Comment: It may seem harsh to place this On Hold as non-reproducible but with no one answering or commenting in over two years, if it remains an issue then I think it is time to revise it with more information from your testing at the latest release you have access to.